# How do I install Oracle 11gR2?

Tags: installation, oracle

I need your valuable help and advise on installing Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu desktop edition 11.10 (64 bit). I was to install 11g which is normally installed on RHEL or OEL and not looking to install 11g client version. Kindly help. If you are aware of any links please share the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that is not supported

[Operating system requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24322/pre_install.htm#CHDFFBIF)

The following or later versions of the operating system are required for Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2):

```
Asianux Server 3 SP2

Oracle Linux 4 Update 7

Oracle Linux 5 Update 2

Oracle Linux 5 Update 5 (with the Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel for Linux)

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 Update 7

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 Update 2

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 Update 5 (with the Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel for Linux)

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP2

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11
```

2.2.2 System Architecture

To determine whether the system architecture can run the software, enter the following command:

uname -m

Note:
Verify that the processor architecture matches the Oracle software release to install. If you do not see the expected output, then you cannot install the software on this system.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Oracle 11gR2 enterprise edition on Ubuntu 16.04. However, there were a number of pitfalls along the way. Here are the links that provided the key information

Overall, follow the directions in this tutorial:

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/03/28/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-lts-64bit-easy-guide/

The installation will fail as it tries to link the Oracle binaries.

Look at the following link for two of the common problems.

https://www.uxora.com/oracle/dba/23-oracle-installation-errors-and-fixes

The above link will help get past the issue with memcpy@GLIBC_2.14 not found, and also with helping ins_ctx.mk build correctly.

However, there will be more build problems, and the following page has the solution for them.

https://community.oracle.com/message/11201245#11201245

After applying all the patches above you could even link oracle yourself if the GUI installer is getting stuck, as follows:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib
mv config.o config.o.bad
relink all
```