# How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, oracle

Please provide me with the guidance to install oracle 11gr2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You can refer the installation procedure link http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Oracle 11gR2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110394/how-do-i-install-oracle-11gr2)

Answer (score 78):

#### 1. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) Oracle Database Express Edition.

#### 2. Instructions before installing Oracle database

1. Copy the downloaded file and paste it in home directory.
2. Unzip using the downloaded .zip file:

   ```
    unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
   ```
3. Install required packages:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc # still works in 22.04
   ```
4. Change directories to the Disk1 directory:

   ```
    cd Disk1/
   ```
5. Convert .rpm package format to .deb package format (that is used by Ubuntu):

   ```
    sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
   ```
6. Create the required chkconfig script:

   ```
    sudo nano /sbin/chkconfig
   ```

   The nano text editor is started and the commands are shown at the bottom of the screen. Now copy and paste the following into the file and save:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Oracle 11gR2 XE installer chkconfig hack for Ubuntu
    file=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe
    if [[ ! `tail -n1 $file | grep INIT` ]]; then
        echo >> $file
        echo '### BEGIN INIT INFO' >> $file
        echo '# Provides: OracleXE' >> $file
        echo '# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
        echo '# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
        echo '# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5' >> $file
        echo '# Default-Stop: 0 1 6' >> $file
        echo '# Short-Description: Oracle 11g Express Edition' >> $file
        echo '### END INIT INFO' >> $file
    fi
    update-rc.d oracle-xe defaults 80 01
   ```
7. Change the permission of the chkconfig file:

   ```
    sudo chmod 755 /sbin/chkconfig
   ```
8. Set kernel parameters. Oracle 11gR2 XE requires additional kernel parameters which you need to set using the command:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf
   ```
9. Copy the following into the file and save:

   ```
    # Oracle 11g XE kernel parameters 
    fs.file-max=6815744  
    net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000  
    kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128 
    kernel.shmmax=536870912
   ```
10. Verify the changes:

    ```
    sudo cat /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf
    ```
11. You should see what you entered earlier. Now load the kernel parameters:

    ```
    sudo service procps start # If this doesn't work try sudo systemctl start procps
    ```
12. Verify the new parameters are loaded:

    ```
    sudo sysctl -q fs.file-max
    ```

You should see the file-max value that you entered earlier.

13. Set up `/dev/shm` mount point for Oracle. Create the following file:

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load
    ```
14. Copy the following into the file and save.

    ```
    #!/bin/sh
    case "$1" in
    start)
        mkdir /var/lock/subsys 2>/dev/null
        touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
        rm /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
        mkdir /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
    *)
        echo error
        exit 1
        ;;

    esac
    ```
15. Change the permissions of the file:

    ```
    sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load
    ```
16. Run the following commands:

    ```
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk 
    sudo mkdir /var/lock/subsys 
    sudo touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
    sudo reboot
    ```

#### 3. Install Oracle database

1. Install Oracle DBMS:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Configure Oracle:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
   ```
3. Setup environment variables by editing your .bashrc file:

   ```
   nano ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. Add the following lines to the end of the file:

   ```
    export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
    export ORACLE_SID=XE
    export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
    export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. Load the changes by executing your profile:

   ```
   . ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Start Oracle 11gR2 XE:

   ```
    sudo service oracle-xe start
   ```
7. Add user YOURUSERNAME to group dba using the command:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G dba YOURUSERNAME
   ```

#### 4. Using the Oracle XE command shell

1. Start the Oracle XE 11gR2 server:

   ```
   sudo service oracle-xe start
   ```
2. Start command-line shell as the system admin:

   ```
   sqlplus sys as sysdba
   ```

   Enter the password that you gave while configuring Oracle earlier. You will now be placed in a SQL environment that only understands SQL commands.
3. Create a regular user account in Oracle using the SQL command:

   ```
   create user USERNAME identified by PASSWORD;
   ```

   Replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with the username and password of your choice. Please remember this username and password. If you had error executing the above with a message about resetlogs, then execute the following SQL command and try again:

   ```
   alter database open resetlogs;
   ```
4. Grant privileges to the user account using the SQL command:

   ```
   grant connect, resource to USERNAME;
   ```

   Replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with the username and password of your choice. Please remember this username and password.
5. Exit the sys admin shell using the SQL command:

   ```
   exit;
   ```
6. Start the command-line shell as a regular user using the command:

   ```
   sqlplus
   ```

Now you can run SQL commands.

Comment: At step 6 I am getting `Starting Oracle Net Listener...touch: cannot touch '/var/lock/subsys/listener': No such file or directory
Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details`

Comment: @Skynet. I got the same error. Although i don't able to understand these [commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136713/installation-of-oracle-database-11g-express-edition-on-ubuntu-12-04-1-lts/14138741#14138741), i tried and able to configure oracle XE or linux mint.

Comment: @Skynet. And also tried this [link](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html). Search content Reference in the comment after expand :  to get it to work I needed to add the following lines in the beginning of the file "/etc/init.d/oracle-xe"...between steps 6(i) and  6(ii)

if [ -L /dev/shm ]; then
    rm -rf /dev/shm
    mkdir /dev/shm
    mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm
fi

if [ ! -d /var/lock/subsys ]; then
 mkdir /var/lock/subsys
 touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
fi

Comment: This is "the" perfect guide to install oracle on ubuntu 14.04. Above comments by @Jeet are also very helpful and work.

Comment: Exact steps, nothing else was needed for me to get oracle up and running !!

Comment: I'm getting this error "Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details" while running this commnad. "sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure"

Comment: `/etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load` seems missing `;;` indicating the end of an alternative at line 7.

Comment: when i try to create the user i get:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Comment: @Eric Carvalho  
Here it is mentioned for XE Edition...i want to install 11g database on linux. let me know how to install the Oracle 11gR2(Standard Edition) on linux (Ubuntu)...

Comment: @Saikat Kundu ...Could you guide me on this?

Comment: The script at step 2.14 is wrong by not actually including the mount command and will therefore cause the error mentioned in the other answers and comments.  Reviewers are, however, idiots. After [the first](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/759929) and [the second](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/760715) attempt to correct the script have failed I give up. Apparently it's more important to mindlessly vote to score points then to actually try to understand what is being done

Comment: Had to use `sudo service procps restart` instead of `sudo service procps start`

Comment: This works just fine in Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you very much

Comment: On a bare-bones installation of Ubuntu with only the core system installed, the required package `bc` isn't installed - while this is probably on most ubuntu machines already, it might be worth adding this to the list of required packages.

Comment: Where more I can download oracle? I cannot to registered on oracle.com for downloading - not comings registration letter!

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine, however I got the following error:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
[....] Starting oracle-xe (via systemctl): oracle-xe.serviceJob for oracle-xe.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status oracle-xe.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

Looking into it:

```
systemctl status oracle-xe.service
Jan 27 10:01:05 <myusername> su[29699]: No passwd entry for user 'oracle'
```

I resolved it by simply adding a user:

```
sudo adduser oracle
```

Hope this helps someone.