# Configuring oracle 11g database on ubuntu 14.04 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details

Tags: 14.04, oracle

I am stuck with oracle 11g database configuration on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I know this question has been answered many times.

I have tried every thing and for two days i am stuck with this error. I desperately need to configure this.

Installation tutorial
[How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Every thing works perfectly fine until this step

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
.
.
Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0  /xe/config/log for details
```

I know this is a hostname issue as most blogs and forums suggest but it is not working for me.

```
$hostname
$josh 

$cat /etc/hosts 
$127.0.0.1  josh


root@josh:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log# ls
cloneDBCreation.log  CloneRmanRestore.log  postDBCreation.log


root@josh:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log# grep ORA *
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
cloneDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
CloneRmanRestore.log:ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
CloneRmanRestore.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
CloneRmanRestore.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
CloneRmanRestore.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
postDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
postDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
postDBCreation.log:ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
postDBCreation.log:ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
postDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
postDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
postDBCreation.log:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

Things that i already tried
https://askubuntu.com/questions/631681/database-configuration-failed-look-into-u01-app-oracle-product-11-2-0-xe-confi

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545412/problems-installing-oracle-database-express-edition-11g

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957137/oracle-11g-xe-installation-error-database-configuration-failed

and many many more.

Answer (score 0):

See if [Oracle-xe installation on ubuntu 14.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770291/oracle-xe-installation-on-ubuntu-14-4/770404#770404) helps ... I list a pdf document you can download that goes through step-by-step from the official download through conversion to *.deb and installation to testing with SQL*Plus.

-Frank