# Oracle-xe installation on ubuntu 14.4

Tags: 14.04, oracle

i have installed Oracle 11g express as follows site http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html 
after installing, i m facing such problem as given below

$ sudo service oracle-xe start[sudo] password for sunil: 
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 64 bit Ubuntu? Last time I looked, it won't run on 32 bit systems regardless of any efforts you make.

I've put a complete(?) tutorial on using Oracle-xe on 64 bit Ubuntu on
http://www.antikytherapubs.com/ that should get you going. I put this together after attempting to use several other on-line instructions that I couldn't get to work, although I don't believe I'm familiar with the site you mentioned. One difficulty is that Oracle doesn't supply a .deb themselves, and some .deb files built on certain systems don't always contain all the dependencies.

Scroll down that page and you'll see a link to either view or download the Database Design Note for using Oracle on Ubuntu (and other Debian based systems).

A version of this app note was also published in an earlier issue of Full Circle magazine - a free monthly Ubuntu magazine if you're not familiar with it (several years of back issues available if you're just getting started with Ubuntu).

I hope this helps.

Frank