# Problem in Installing the oracle DBMS in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, oracle

I have installed oracle 11g R2 in ubuntu 12.04,by referring the below link 
[How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04) (answered by @Saikat Kundu)

I have done till Step 2(Configuration setting before oracle installation).
In step 3 (Install oracle),Im getting the below error.

```
$ sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
(--install):  cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:  oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Did Step 5.2 (`sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm`) create a `.deb`file? Maybe different version number?

Comment: .deb file is created.           $sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
mkdir: cannot create directory `oracle-xe-11.2.0': File exists
unable to mkdir oracle-xe-11.2.0:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257

Comment: The message only says it cannot create a directory - does not say that .deb file exists. Seems there is a file named `oracle-xe-11.2.0`, but should be a directory.

Comment: oracle-xe-11.2.0 - Directory is there.so file is not there.                                  ls -lrt
total 309896
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 317320273 Aug 29  2011 oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root      4096 Aug 29  2011 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Aug 29  2011 response
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Feb  8 10:35 oracle-xe-11.2.0

Comment: What is inside directory `oracle-xe-11.2.0`?

Comment: these are files inside oracle-xe-11.2.0.                                                                       $ ls -lrt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  8 10:35 etc
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  8 10:35 u01

Comment: I'ld suggest to start over again with an empty directory at Step2, skipping 2.3, up to 2.5. Make sure there is no error shown with `sudo alien...`, and if it is successful, look for the `.deb` file: `find . -name \*.deb -ls`.

Comment: shall i have to remove old directories and files which were created during installation...?

Comment: That's what I recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ridgy . I have removed the files and tried install from scratch,  database configured successfully...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `oracle-xe-11.2.0` in the **Disk1** folder and then run the following command

```
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

to convert `.rpm` file to `.deb` package