# configuration error in oracle

Tags: command-line, 16.04, oracle

i am trying to install oracle 11g tool, but i am getting this error while configuring it. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

More detailed: I followed this to install oracle [How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Everything went fine till step 3, i installed the oracle .deb file and in the next step when i try to configure oracle with this command

> sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

i am getting database configuration failed error.

THE ERROR LOG FILE

```
Create controlfile reuse set database "XE"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


BEGIN dbms_backup_restore.zerodbid(0); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
Create controlfile reuse set database "XE"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter system enable restricted session
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter database "XE" open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter database rename global_name to "XE"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter system switch logfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter system checkpoint
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter database drop logfile group 3
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/temp.dbf' SIZE 20480K REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name='USERS'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


select sid, program, serial#, username from v$session
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter user sys identified by "oracle"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter user system identified by "oracle"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


alter system disable restricted session
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error into your post...and post the oracle log file also!

Comment: It would be substantially easier to diagnose your issue if you would replace the picture of your screen with the actual text that you have on the screen.  The picture is unnecessarily cumbersome to process.  It's hard to make out when we can't use our normal font settings.  Also, we can't copy and paste the text in performing research.  Thanks in advance if you would provide the actual text output.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gawk`.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gawk
sudo update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/gawk
awk
```

Comment: It says no installation candidate found

Comment: @Sazzy I've updated my answer. Please try again. After installing, in `terminal` type `awk` to confirm that it's there now.

Comment: i did it with no luck

Comment: @Sazzy please explain. My answer didn't work, or it didn't solve the problem? Tell me exactly where it might have failed.

Comment: ps: edit your answer to include the `terminal` output of `update-alternatives --display awk`. Let me know.

Comment: gawk got installed successfully but that did not solve the problem. I will update the question in sometime, because i am not facing this issue my friend is.

Comment: @Sazzy did the `awk` command work you were in the terminal? That's why your Oracle was failing. If not, I'll need to give you another command to finish the answer and solve the problem.

Comment: The gawk command worked, i installed it. But the awk command did not work.

Comment: @Sazzy I've updated my answer with `sudo update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/gawk` then `awk` and it should work now. Then try your Oracle again.

Comment: ok thank you, i will let you know the results.