# oracle express edition installation error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: oracle

I'm new user to ubuntu please help me out. [I have used this process to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04) but the following error occurred:

[image: photo]

Comment: The second command you tried didn't work because the first one didn't work. You have to make the package first, then install it. Just looking at your terminal, it looks like you've skipped the whole of step 2 and moved onto step 3.

Comment: yeah that's what first command is the install command and it didn't worked out

Comment: Again, it didn't work because there's no package for it to install. That's what step 2 of that answer does (amongst other things); makes the package.

Comment: but i've done the same process step by step as given in the link i provided

Comment: You skipped step 3 and following.

Comment: the first command seen in the terminal is the first command of step 3 installation process (process is in the link specified) it said to reboot before step3 so i did