# bash: /home/floyd/.profile: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, oracle

I was following this hints to install oracle [How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)  and everything went right  till Step 3 (5)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a mistake in the tuto : it makes you change things in `~/.bashrc`and then ask you to source `~/.profile` (that doesn't exist)

try

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

instead of

```
. ~/.profile
```

Comment: It worked as it doesn't shows any previous output but when i try to run the code in Step 5 (6) the oracle doesn't start,  after i enter the sudo service oracle-xe start  it takes me to another line of terminal and there is no any sign of running oracle. Can you please help ?

Comment: Did you try to continue the tutorial ? It's possible that the command ' sudo service oracle-xe start' worked and did not output anything

Comment: Yes i am following every step of tutorial and this code doesn't output anything

Comment: What does the command ' sudo service oracle-xe status ' answer ?

Comment: Command answers nothing, it directs to another line of command immediately