# Problem with Oracle Database XE Install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, oracle, database

I am newbie with Ubuntu, but I'm trying to install Oracle Database XE 11g, using this tutorial:
[Link to Ubuntu Tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)

My Ubuntu isn't 14-04, it's 18.04, but I cam getting this error on

> Step 4. 3. Create a regular user account in Oracle using the SQL command...

```
target@target-Lenovo-G700:~$ sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat May 18 20:25:54 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> create user target identified by 12345678;
create user target identified by 12345678
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

If anyone can help me, I will be very thankful. I can provide you with more information if you need, and please, don't judge me, I am newbie. To get to this point of installation it took me whole day.

Comment: Check the service is running with `systemctl status oracle-xe`. Might also try logging in with `sqlplus / as sysdba` and run the `startup` command inside sqlplus. Other than that, search online for this `ORA-01034: ORACLE not available` error code, which e.g. returns https://community.oracle.com/thread/439003. Unrelated, I would generally recommend not to install Oracle XE on Ubuntu at all. Oracle only packaged it in rpm format for systems like RHEL, Fedora, CentOS or SuSE and it also deeply integrates itself into the system, making it hard to ever remove. I would prefer running it in a VM.

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks a lot for your advice. I tried, but the problem seemed to be with the whole installation. I tried a lot of these tutorials, but as you said - Oracle XE is not meant to be in Ubuntu (not the easy way, for what is certain). So uninstalling it all and I will try with VM, because I am learning PL/SQL and need Oracle on my PC. Thanks again!